# Is it possible to access camera on iOS webview (Angular 7)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am new with iOS and trying to build iOS app webview Angular 7 with ability to access camera for scanning QRCodes.

I have added camera privacy on info.plist:

> Key: Privacy - Camera Usage Description
>
> Value: This app requires access to the camera for scan barcodes.

but when I use camera feature it shows black screen (tested on a device).

It works fine if I open web app thought safari.

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: @EneaDume I have brought webview iOS app from https://zeroqode.com/native, then just set target url point to my web app, so which part of code you want to know Angular or iOS? (I build only Angular part)